# Blazor, updating shared state in OnInitializedAsync with awaited object

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have the following code in a Blazor component:

```cs
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        appBarState.Title = "Analyses";
        project = await ApiService.GetFromJsonAsync<ProjectDTO>($"api/Projects/{ProjId}/dto");
        // TODO: Not working
        appBarState.Title = $"Analyses for project {project?.Name}";
        Console.WriteLine($"Analyses for project {project?.Name}");
    }
```

The intention is to set the top app bar with a default title, call the API to get more information about the object, and update the app bar with more accurate information using the shared `AppBarState` class below.

```cs
public class AppBarState
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The app bar title is set to `Analyses`, the API is called and the correct value is returned. The `Console.WriteLine` line for `$"Analyses for project {project?.Name}"` works correctly, however trying to update the shared state with this value is not successful. The app bar title remains as `Analyses`, not even `Analyses for project` .

I'm assuming the issue is with updating shared state after an `await` call as trying to update the app bar state after the `await` call with any value (plain string without referencing `project`) fails to update.

Comment: What do you mean with 'shared state', are you trying to create state management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that you are displaying the title in a different component or in the layout.

Add an event and a setter to AppBarState and register it as a Scoped DI service:

```
public class AppBarState
{
    public event EventHandler? TitleChanged;
    
    public string? Title { get; private set; }

    public void SetTitle(string title)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.NotifyTitleChanged();
    }

    public void NotifyTitleChanged()
        => this.TitleChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Program:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AppBarState>();
```

Here's a component to display the title:

```
@inject AppBarState appBarState
@implements IDisposable

<h3>@this.appBarState.Title</h3>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    => appBarState.TitleChanged += this.OnTitleChanged;

    // Kick off a re-redner event on the component
    private void OnTitleChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    => this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
     => appBarState.TitleChanged -= this.OnTitleChanged;
}
```

Here's a test page to show it working:

```
@page "/"

@inject AppBarState appBarState;

<h1>Hello</h1>

<TitleBar />

@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        appBarState.SetTitle("Loading");
        // Emulate an async data get
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        appBarState.SetTitle($"Loaded at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
StateHasChanged()
```

after updating the value of title